# Reset react component props in a single test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that display text base on state ('success' or 'loading')

```
const Button = (state) => <button>{state === 'success' ? 'Sucess!' : state === 'loading' ? 'Please wait...' : ''}</button>
```

and I've to write test like so:

```
test('Button approved state', () => {
    render(<Button state="success" />)
    expect(screen.getByText('Sucess!'))
})

test('Button pending state', () => {
    render(<Button state="loading" />)
    expect(screen.getByText('Please wait...'))
})
```

Is it possible to them in one test? I tried

```
test('Button approved and pending state', () => {
    render(<Button state="success" />)
    expect(screen.getByText('Sucess!'))

    //need to reset here?

    render(<Button state="loading" />)
    expect(screen.getByText('Please wait...'))
})
```

the test failed. how do I do some sort of reset in between?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in one test? Seems much clearer separately--there are two different behaviors here.

Comment: You can try ```describe``` to group several test cases, Also if you wanna reset the component itself, try rendering it again with specific props for specific test cases.

Comment: What error is being thrown? also i think your button component should have `{` and `}`  wrapping `state`, like this `const Button = ({state}) => ...`.

Comment: @ggorlen imagine you have a bunch of state, it seems repetitive.

Comment: Each `it` block should test one thing. The idea is to isolate one precise behavior when a test fails. Following your logic to its conclusion, why not avoid repetition and put all code into one `it`? The answer should be pretty obvious--when something fails, it's hard to tell what went wrong. You can factor out some repetition with `before`/`describe`, but generally repetition is OK in tests if they're explicit. If you want precision, maybe use the `getByText` returned by the specific `render` rather than `screen`, which I'm guessing uses the first render since it wasn't cleaned up.

Comment: what's wrong with using just `test`?